# Stored procedure, if exists return ID or insert and return ID

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a pretty simple DB2 stored procedure where I'm taking in a parameter string and inserting it into a table, which works fine but I really need to expand it. Currently it looks like this:

```
    IN_TAG_DATA


    P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

    INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TAGS(TAG_DATA)
    VALUES(IN_TAG_DATA);

    END P1
```

What I need to do now is put in the same string parameter but based on that param, I need to check if the name exists already and if so select/return the id of it. If it doesn't exist, I need to insert it and THEN return the created ID.

How should I alter this in order to get the appropriate function here?

```
    IN_TAG_DATA
    OUT_TAG_ID

    P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

    DECLARE V_TAG_ID INTEGER;

    SELECT CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA . TAG_ID_SEQ AS INTEGER)
    INTO V_TAG_ID
    FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1;

    /*
    IF EXISTS BASED ON IN_TAG_DATA, GET ID ELSE INSERT AND RETURN created ID
    */


    SET OUT_TAG_ID
    END P1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TABLE TAGS(TAG_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, TAG_DATA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL) IN USERSPACE1@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TAGS(P_TAG_DATA VARCHAR(20), OUT P_TAG_ID INT)
BEGIN

FOR C1 AS 
  WITH E (TAG_ID) AS (
    SELECT TAG_ID
    FROM TAGS
    WHERE TAG_DATA=P_TAG_DATA
  )
  , I AS (
    SELECT TAG_ID
    FROM NEW TABLE (
      INSERT INTO TAGS (TAG_DATA) 
      SELECT P_TAG_DATA FROM TABLE(VALUES 1)
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM E)
    )
  )
  SELECT COALESCE(E.TAG_ID, I.TAG_ID) TAG_ID
  FROM I FULL JOIN E ON 1=1

  DO
    SET P_TAG_ID = C1.TAG_ID;
  END FOR;

END@
```

A little bit complicated, but...
All actions needed can be performed by this single statement.  `E` contains a `TAG_ID` value if it exists. We insert a new row only if it doesn't exist, and retrieve inserted `TAG_ID` using SELECT FROM [data-change-table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html). Finally, we join existing row and inserted one. Only one of them exists, and we get one of these `TAG_IDs`.

If you are at Db2 for LUW 11.1, then `FOR` loop is not needed - the `SELECT INTO` statement supports CTE, so one can use just a single statement with `SELECT COALESCE(E.TAG_ID, I.TAG_ID) INTO P_TAG_ID` without a loop. Prior Db2 versions don't support it, so, we have to use `FOR` loop just to retrieve a single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
IN_TAG_DATA
OUT_TAG_ID

P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC
```

Check if the TAG ID exists in the database

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TAG_ID FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1 WHERE xx = TAG_DATA) 
THEN
```

Return TAG ID

```
BEGIN
SET OUT_TAG_ID = TAG_ID
END;
ELSE
```

insert it and then return the created ID

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TAGS(TAG_DATA)
VALUES(IN_TAG_DATA)
SET OUT_TAG_ID = TAG_ID
END;
END IF;

END P1
```

Comment: Thank you, what exactly is missing in the first begin/end block though?

Comment: Because in the first block I want to check if the tag_data matches but then return the tag_id

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.